# Rebuilding indexes on a linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which retrieves a list of my linked servers, builds a list of their databases and rebuilds any table index with a certain level of fragmentation and a certain number of pages.

The one issue I'm having is when I actually  execute the rebuild command. My code is:

```
SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX' + QUOTENAME(@index) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(@servername) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table) +   ' REBUILD;'

EXECUTE sp_sqlexec @cmd
```

The error I'm getting is:

"Cannot find the object "*ServerName.Databasename*.dbo.*IndexName*" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions"

*I've replaced the Server, Database and Index names but the four-part identifier displays correctly in the error message.*

I'm wondering if rebuilding an index on a linked server is possible and if so, what permissions are required. Anyone else tried this sort of thing?

Thanks

Comment: just look at following link that might answer your question [LINK](http://serverfault.com/a/75411)

Comment: Thanks Naveen, but it doesn't really give me the answer I'm after. I could create procedures on my linked servers and execute them remotely, but I'm trying to avoid creating anything on the linked servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I think I've got it. In case anyone else has this problem, try something like:

```
    SET @cmd = '
 EXEC(''ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(@index) + ' ON ' + @dbname + '.' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table) +  ' REBUILD'') AT ' + QUOTENAME(@servername) + ' '

EXECUTE sp_sqlexec @cmd
```